# Solve using PolyGamma function

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages, special-functions, variable-definitions, numerical-value

I am trying to solve for the value of y.

My code is:

```
x = 0.165; 

f = -Log[y] - PolyGamma[0.5 + 0.2*(x/y)] + PolyGamma[0.5]; 

Solve[f == 0, y]
```

Running gave me

> Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or >the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the >system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing >Solve with an exact version of the system may help.

Using *MATLAB* gave me a value of y.

Comment: ``FindRoot[f, {y, .1, 2}] (* {y -> 0.8324921392608208`} *)``

Comment: Or:  `Minimize[Abs[-Log[y] - PolyGamma[0.5 + 0.033/y] + PolyGamma[0.5]], y]`

Answer (score 3):

`Solve` is a symbolic solver of algebraic as well as various types of transcendental equations and consequently we should use exact numbers.

```
x = Rationalize[0.165];
f[y_] := -Log[y] - PolyGamma[1/2 + 1/5 (x/y)] + PolyGamma[1/2]
```

Next we should restrict the domain of `y`, a natural assumption is `y > 0`, nevertheless one should also add a bound from above (this is not always necessary). Taking a look at e.g. `Plot[f[y], {y, 0, 5}]`, we should be satisfied with `0 < y < 5`, and so `Solve`
provides an exact solution in terms of the `Root` object:

```
y /. First @ FullSimplify[ Solve[ f[y] == 0 && 0 < y < 5, y]]
```

> ```
> Root[{EulerGamma + Log[4] + Log[#1] + PolyGamma[0, 1/2 + 33/(1000*#1)]&,
>       0.8324921392608209131327584577663713541314494518823960255129`30
>       .102999566398122}]
> ```

This solution can be further transformed **symbolically** for more detailed purposes.
Using a bound for `y` we could use `NSolve` as well without rationalizing inexact coefficients to get a numerical solution, however an exact solution is a full information we can get from the given equation.  Our solution can be represented in terms of `HarmonicNumber` if we appropriately simplify `f`, e.g.

```
fs = FullSimplify[ f[y], y > 0]
```

> ```
> -HarmonicNumber[-(1/2) + 33/(1000 y)] - Log[4 y]
> ```

```
y /. First @ Solve[fs == 0 && 0 < y < 5, y]
```

> ```
> Root[{HarmonicNumber[-1/2 + 33/(1000*#1)] + Log[4*#1]&,
>       0.8324921392608209131327584577663713541314494518823960255129`
>       30.102999566398122}]
> ```

The assumption that `y > 0` yields a real solution. There are also complex solutions, without specifying them we can get an insight where they can be found with `ContourPlot`, e.g.

```
ContourPlot[{ Re[f[u + I w]] == 0, Im[f[u + I w]] == 0}, 
            { u, -0.095, 0.005}, {w, -0.07, 0.07}, 
            PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ContourStyle -> Thick, 
            AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

and slightly more detailed neighbourhood of the singular point (it takes a while)

```
ContourPlot[{ Re[f[u + I w]] == 0, Im[f[u + I w]] == 0}, 
            {u, -0.023, -0.003}, {w, -0.008, 0.008}, 
            PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
            ContourStyle -> Thick, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply and now with the help of your instruction problem is solved.

Comment: @Suman 
You are welcome. I recommend providing more detailed information why such an equation is interesting. Perhaps some further subtleties might appear crucial to get a deepper understanding.  My motivation to provide an answer was checking certain properties of the `PolyGamma` function..